# How disable Redis log in Rails log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I can disable SQL logging in Rails by set:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

How I can disable Redis logging?

Comment: What Redis client and Redis-using libraries are you using? Redis is not a default part of the Rails stack, so we need more information to give an answer.

Comment: @RobertNubel Redis version 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it, in `config/initializers/redis.rb` change:

```
#REDIS.client.logger = Rails.logger
REDIS.client.logger = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload the Redis configuration file please,
There should be a settings for this:

```
# To enable logging to the system logger, just set 'syslog-enabled' to yes,
# and optionally update the other syslog parameters to suit your needs.
# syslog-enabled no
```

You can view the 'Redis configuration file example' at [http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf](http://Hi,%20Can%20you%20upload%20the%20Redis%20configuration%20file%20please,%20There%20should%20be%20a%20settings%20for%20this:%20%20#%20To%20enable%20logging%20to%20the%20system%20logger,%20just%20set%20'syslog-enabled'%20to%20yes,%20#%20and%20optionally%20update%20the%20other%20syslog%20parameters%20to%20suit%20your%20needs.%20#%20syslog-enabled%20no%20%20%20You%20can%20view%20the%20'Redis%20configuration%20file%20example'%20at%20http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf%20%20%20%20the%20configuration%20file%20should%20be%20at:%20/etc/redis.conf)

the configuration file should be at: `/etc/redis.conf`